# Using multiple tables in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm trying to make an api,but I can only find example of using a single table. This is one of the examples I found that I want to replicate, but with more tables.

http://mopsled.com/2013/01/building-restful-api/

Also this code creates the database on every run. How would you set it up so that it only makes the database once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you got two tables named `albums` and `tracks` that you want created only once, Both of your requests are on those lines of code:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'albums'
    create_table :albums do |table|
      table.column :title,     :string
      table.column :performer, :string
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'tracks'
    create_table :tracks do |table|
      table.column :album_id,     :integer
      table.column :track_number, :integer
      table.column :title,        :string
    end
  end
end
```

You can get more info by [reading this article.](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/sqlite-and-activerecord/)

Comment: Did my answer helped you ?
If yes, please accept it by clicking on the accept button below the arrow on the left of my answer